# display all json data with bootstrap card in a dynamic div using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

i'm still learning ajax,jquery and js here.. So in this problem i want to get the json data and display each of it into div id="card-body" dynamically one by one per ID, but it seems my code doesn't work because the result only show one div that have all the data inside of it. Are there any suggestion that can be added or changed within the code here?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
        </div>
        <div class="addDiv">
            <div id="card-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
                success: function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                        var userId = item.userId;
                        var typeId = item.id;
                        var titleId = item.title;
                        var bodyId = item.body;
                        var $info = $("<p/>").html("user id: " + userId + "<br>"
                            + "id: " + typeId + "<br>"
                            + "title: " + titleId + "<br>"
                            + "body: " + bodyId);

                        var html = '<div id="card-body>';

                        for (let i = 0; i < $(result).length; i++) {
                            const element = $(result)[i];
                        }

                            html += '</div>';

                            $(".addDiv").append(html);

                        $("div#card-body").append($info);
                    });
                    // console.log('success', result);
                    // console.log(result[0].body);
                    // console.log($(result).length);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You would need to concatenate the html var you are building with $info before closing it and after that append it to .addDiv. IDs should be used only once, they are unique identifiers, use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < $(result).length; i++) {
  const element = $(result)[i];
}
```

what is here going to do?

or you mean this? --- Updated

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    success: function(result) {
      var container = $("div#list");
      $.each(result, function (index, item) {
        var userId = item.userId;
        var id = "card-body-" + userId;
        var el = $('div#' + id)
        console.log(el)
        var typeId = item.id;
        var titleId = item.title;
        var bodyId = item.body;
        var $info = $('<div>').html(
          "user id: " + userId + "<br>" +
          "id: " + typeId + "<br>" +
          "title: " + titleId + "<br>" +
          "body: " + bodyId
        );
        if (!el.length) {
          // not found, create new one
          el = $('<div id="' + id + '">')
          container.append(el)
        }
        el.append($info)
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: oops my bad, i forgot to sort out the loop... what i meant is to create the div become dynamic so after i get the data json, it will separate every userID into each div (example: userID : 1 in "div id=card-body" , userID : 2 in "div id=card-body-2" ,etc) sorry for troubling you, i'm a bit confused myself how to explain the problem here..

Comment: sorry for late reply.. it solved my problem, thanks a lot for the help!